# Lambda expression, how to pass method as parameter in custom method

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am working on personal project, and found out I could duplicate less code if applied lambda.

So current code looks like that:

```
public UserDto findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, char[] password) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        String ejbUrl = "ejb:ShopManagmentEAR/ShopManagmentEJB//FrontController!"+IFrontControllerRemote.class.getName();

        IFrontControllerRemote bean = (IFrontControllerRemote) ctx.lookup(ejbUrl);
        return bean.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public List<CategoryDto> getAllCategories(){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        String ejbUrl = "ejb:ShopManagmentEAR/ShopManagmentEJB//FrontController!"+IFrontControllerRemote.class.getName();

        IFrontControllerRemote bean = (IFrontControllerRemote) ctx.lookup(ejbUrl);
        return bean.getAllCategories();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you can see both methods differ only in the type returned and the method at the return statement. So I am pretty sure that lambda could help me clear the code, but unfortunately I can't understand this topic.

Comment: Not a lambda, but you could move the code needed to retrieve your `bean` to a utility method and call it in both of your current methods (that is, the common code is around getting `IFrontControllerRemote`.

Comment: I'd say the biggest problem here is the manual bean lookup, and putting lambdas there wouldn't really help the general quality.

Comment: This sample code is from fatClient side, so i cant inject code with help of the @EJB annotation

Comment: Why not just move the part that returns the bean into a separate method?  This will probably work out simpler than using lambdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a generic method

```
private <T> queryBean(Function<IFrontControllerRemote,T> transform) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        String ejbUrl = "ejb:ShopManagmentEAR/ShopManagmentEJB//FrontController!"+IFrontControllerRemote.class.getName();

        IFrontControllerRemote bean = (IFrontControllerRemote) ctx.lookup(ejbUrl);

        return transform.apply(bean);

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

with the calls

```
return queryBean(bean -> bean.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password));
```

and

```
return queryBean(bean::getAllCategories);
```

respectively.

Answer (score 2):

In order to take advantage of lambda expressions (or method references), you should try to figure out how the difference between the two method can be expressed by a functional interface (i.e. an interface having a single method).

Both of your methods obtain the return value from a `IFrontControllerRemote` instance. Therefore, a generic method may accept a `Function<IFrontControllerRemote,T>`, where `T` represents the returned value. The `Function<IFrontControllerRemote,T>` instance will accept a `IFrontControllerRemote` and return the required value.

```
public <T> T getProperty(Function<IFrontControllerRemote,T> retriever) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        String ejbUrl = "ejb:ShopManagmentEAR/ShopManagmentEJB//FrontController!"+IFrontControllerRemote.class.getName();

        IFrontControllerRemote bean = (IFrontControllerRemote) ctx.lookup(ejbUrl);
        return retriever.apply(bean);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, to call the method:

```
UserDto user = getProperty (b -> b.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password));

List<CategoryDto> list = getProperty (IFrontControllerRemote::getAllCategories);
```